# MySQL query select all were date is equal to today on datetime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, select

I have a database table something like this:

```
Col_1    |   Datetime
test1      2015-12-19 09:00:00
test2      2015-12-18 12:30:00
test3      2015-12-19 10:00:00
test4      2015-12-19 16:45:00
```

I am trying to select in my query all results where the `datetime` is equal to today's date, although when I simply use something like:

`$today = date("Y-m-d");
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime = '$today'`

It just doesn't seem to work? And if I add the time in to `$today` it would only select those results which are equal to the exact current time which is not what I want?

Any idea as to how I can do this? I've even gone so far as to this which is totally stupid (Although it was about 3am in the morning when I coded it):

```
   $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('midnight'));
   $todays = date(strtotime('midnight'));
   $take24hours = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', $todays));

    $results = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  date_added > '$take24hours' AND date_added < '$now')"));
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(\`datetime\`) = current_date;`

Comment: Is `current_date;` an automatic function within the select statement?

Comment: current_date is an ansi standard date function which mysql provides to conform

Comment: Seems to work great, if you add your comment as an answer I'll be happy to accept it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do this entirely in sql transaction ( no need for php date formatting ) :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date(`datetime`) = current_date;
```

Answer (score 1):

CURDATE() will get current date.

SELECT * FROM table where DATE(date)=CURDATE()